# iOS requirements for data storage (using cache folder versus marking files not to be backedup)

Tags: ios, data-storage

I got my app rejected due to violation of 2.23

After inspection, it would appear that I was indeed not a correct path for storing downloaded images and data files (i.e. files that I would prefer to have available for offline usage, but which the app **can** re-download again if removed by iOS)

However, after looking at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html

It appears it may not even be enough to proper "cache" path for iOS > 5? Example:

*/var/mobile/Applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/Library/Caches/'*

Will using above make my app pass this requirement? Or am I forced to using the API for making files not to be backed-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the caches directory is correct if you can re-download the files. They will not be backed up. You only need to use the "do not backup" flag if the files exist in a location that normally is backed up (e.g. the documents directory).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you happen to know if there is an official page that states that? Just in case I need it for resolution? (Anyhow, will try resubmit with new data storage path) :)